# How do I set the value of a textbox array element using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

how can i set a value to a textbox array element using jquery.
i have an array of select and corrosponding textbox(array). when i select a diff value from the dropdown, it shud automatically populate the textbox corrosponding to it. also remember this select and textbox are created dynamically.

thanks in advance

Comment: post your current code so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this:

```
var $text = $('#textbox'), $select = $('#selectMenu').change(function(){
  $text.val($select.val())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myTextBox').val($('#mySelectBox').val());
```

You can add onChange to the select box to call the js function to do the above.

Answer (score -1):

You should try something like :

```
$(function () {   
    function changed(select) {
         var newVal = select.value;
         ${"#yourTextBoxID"}.val(newVal);
     }
});
```

... and on your select

onchange="changed(this)"

Comment: Why would you want to use inline event handlers? And your jQuery `$` function should be using parenthesis, not curly braces.

Comment: Why not? I had some troubles with jQuery's change event catcher... (and my bad for the mistype...)